# How to work with .mat file from BSDS500 dataset?

Tags: python, matlab

I want to create the image from the ground truth found in the .mat files from BSDS500 dataset. I want to compare the image from ground truth file with the one generated by my program. I read the content and the output of one of the file is:

```
 [[array([[(array([[ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       ...,
       [36, 36, 36, ..., 36, 36, 36],
       [36, 36, 36, ..., 36, 36, 36],
       [36, 36, 36, ..., 36, 36, 36]], dtype=uint16), array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8))]],
      dtype=[('Segmentation', 'O'), ('Boundaries', 'O')])
  array([[(array([[ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       ...,
       [11, 11, 11, ..., 11, 11, 11],
       [11, 11, 11, ..., 11, 11, 11],
       [11, 11, 11, ..., 11, 11, 11]], dtype=uint16), array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8))]],
      dtype=[('Segmentation', 'O'), ('Boundaries', 'O')])
  array([[(array([[ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1],
       ...,
       [14, 14, 14, ..., 14, 14, 14],
       [14, 14, 14, ..., 14, 14, 14],
       [14, 14, 14, ..., 14, 14, 14]], dtype=uint16), array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8))]],
      dtype=[('Segmentation', 'O'), ('Boundaries', 'O')])
  array([[(array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [6, 6, 6, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 6, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 6, ..., 6, 6, 6]], dtype=uint16), array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8))]],
      dtype=[('Segmentation', 'O'), ('Boundaries', 'O')])
  array([[(array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [9, 9, 9, ..., 9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9, ..., 9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9, ..., 9, 9, 9]], dtype=uint16), array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8))]],
      dtype=[('Segmentation', 'O'), ('Boundaries', 'O')])]]
```

I do not know how to use this in my code in order to check if my segmentation program perform well.

Answer (score 1):

Let's load the matfile:

```
import io
file = io.loadmat(matfilePath)
```

`file` is a dictionnary, and its key `'groundTruth'` has the relevant information. In the following snippet, `edges` has the contours of the image and `segmap` is the segmentation map. Edge arrays are normalized so you will have to multiply them by 255 to get your images.

```
edges = file['groundTruth'][0][0][0][0][1]
segmap = file['groundTruth'][0][0][0][0][0]
segmap_uint8 = segmap_data.astype(np.uint8) # convert to uint8 to prevent lossy conversion when saving image

edges_255 = edges * 255
import imageio
# save images
imageio.imwrite(os.path.join(imagePath,'image_edges.jpg'), edges_255)
imageio.imwrite(os.path.join(imagePath,'image_seg.jpg'), segmap_uint8)
```

Check out these links for the complete code. They contain mat file processing scripts in python and matlab.
[BSDS500 data processing (convert groundtruth to jpg format)](https://www.programmersought.com/article/50936088861/),
[Convert bsds500 data set](https://www.programmersought.com/article/87746626730/)
PS: even if the links are unavailable, the main answer is in the code above.